# How to set UID and GID for the container using python sdk?

Tags: python, docker

How to set UID and GID for the container when [Python SDK](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html) is used to spin up the container?

Comment: "user (str or int) – Username or UID to run commands as inside the container." is right there...

Comment: what about GID?

Comment: "group_add (list) – List of additional group names and/or IDs that the container process will run as."?

Comment: group_add will work with GID or only group name?

Comment: It says "group names and/or IDs".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation you've linked says, pass in `user` and `group_add` to `run()`:

```
client.containers.run('alpine', 'echo hello world', user='foo', group_add=[123])
```

Both accept both IDs and names, but `group_add` needs to be a list.